# I want to prove that $B=S^2 \cap \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_i \geq 0 \}$ is homeomorphic to the disk $B^2= \{ x \in \mathbb{R^2} : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I claim that the map $f:B \to B^2$ defined by $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)=(x_1, x_2, 0)$ is a continious, bijection with $g: B^2 \to B$, $g(x_1, x_2)=(x_1, x_2, \sqrt{1-(x_1^2+x_2^2)})$ it's inverse.

So i claim that $f$ is o homeomorphism with $f^{-1}=g$ $\Longrightarrow$ $B \cong B^2$.

Is that true?

Comment: in the question $B=S^2 \cup \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) : x_i \geq 0 \}$ and $B^2= \{ x=(x_1,x_2) : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$ 

I'm for not writing it properly on the title.

Comment: I'm sorry again. I mean $B=S^2 \cap \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) : x_i \geq 0 \}$

Comment: The way you have written the question, it's ambiguous whether you want all of the coordinates to be positive, or if you want just want coordinate to be positive.

Comment: I want all the coordinates positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I'm rewriting this in light of the comment that $B$ is actually the *intersection* of $S^2$ with the positive orthant rather than the union as originally stated.

In this case, you're correct that they are homeomorphic! To see this, note that these two sets can both be contracted down to a point and are the same dimension.

That said, your functions aren't quite there yet. Your $f$ should take all of $B$ onto all of $B^2$ (whereas right now it only takes it on to the top-right quarter of it).

Comment: I'm sorry again. I mean $B=S^2 \cap \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) : x_i \geq 0 \}$

Comment: @D.Mihailidis I've edited the above to reflect this your comment.  The gist is they are indeed homeomorphic.

Comment: No problem.  Try to have a think about how to fix your homeomorphisms!

Comment: Is that true that the quarter-circle is homeomorphic to the disk? If this is true, I'm done.

Comment: It is true that the quarter-*disk* is homeomorphic to the disk.  Think of the map that first shrinks the quarter disk down to a disk-shaped subset of itself, translates that disk to the origin, then expands it back up 'til its radius 1.